# JQ Change column values

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with 3 columns and some values in them, and I need to make some selector which can change value of "price" between the price with tax and without (in Czech rep. it is 21% now).
Table looks like this:

```
<table id="one-column-emphasis">
<colgroup><col></colgroup>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">...</th>
    <th scope="col">...</th>
    <th scope="col">Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Price of thing</td>
    <td>how long</td>
    <td>4PRICE</td>
  </tr>
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

And for selector use something like:

```
<a href="..">With ax</a>/<a href="..">Without tax</a>
```

[link to table](http://e1cartronic.cz/cenik.html)

Comment: I really dont get your question... could you please specify your question a little bit more?

Comment: and your jquery that you try?

Comment: I am sorry. Its really hard for me to explain it because my english is not that good as i want to. But just easy - i need onclick event which will add tax to my price and on next click change it back to without tax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help you a little bit to start here is [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/M7Vhs/1/) which gives you a idea how you can start your Problem

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th class="priceheader" data-taxstate="n">Price (€)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td class="price">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td class="price">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td class="price">12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="tax">switch tax</button>
```

#### JS

```
var tax = "1.2" //20%
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tax").click(function () {
        if ($(".priceheader").attr("data-taxstate") == "n") {
            $(".price").each(function () {
                $(this).html(parseFloat($(this).html()) * tax);
            });
            $(".priceheader").attr("data-taxstate", "y");
        } else {
            $(".price").each(function () {
                $(this).html(parseFloat($(this).html()) / tax);
            });
            $(".priceheader").attr("data-taxstate", "n");
        }
    });
});
```

But this is just a start. You have to round the right way, and also you have to make it then sure, that there is no single value where switching will change its value.

### Next steps

This is just a start of what you are looking for. You have to round your values and there are also much more beautiful ways to solve that, depending what you try to get :)

Better would be perhaps to calculate the tax value, but save the original value in a data-* attribute and don't calculate back.

Hope this helps you!